# index percolate queries using spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Here is my Dto for percolator query class.

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "#{@es.indexName}")
@Builder(builderClassName = "RuleBuilder")
public class Rule {
    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private QueryBuilder query;
    private RuleDataDto data;

    public static class RuleBuilder {
        private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    }
}
```

Index Mapping

```
{
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "query": {
        "type": "percolator"
      },
      "data": {
        "properties": {
          "subType": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

based on criteria I am generating queries and trying to index those to percolator. but getting below exception

`query malformed, no start_object after query name`

what should be the query field Type? can someone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store an Elasticsearch object (`QueryBuilder`) in Elasticsearch without specifying the mapping type.

You will need to annotate your `query` property as percolator type and might change the type of your property to a `String`:

```java
@Document(indexName = "#{@es.indexName}")
public class Rule {
    @Id
    private String _id;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Percolator)
    private String query;
    
    // ...
}
```

Or, if you want to have some other class for the `query` property you'll need a custom converter that will convert your object into a valid JSON query - see the [documentation for the percolator mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/percolator.html).

Comment: Hi @P.J.Meisch, after updating query property type to String, I am getting 
`parsing_exception, query malformed, must start with start_object`

This is how I am building and saving the query object
```Rule rule = Rule.builder().query(queryBuilder.toString()).data(ruleDataDto).build();
ruleRepository.save(rule);
```

Comment: then please debug and check what String is set int the `query`property. And what does the mapping show for the index ( GET /indexname/_mapping)?

Comment: it is stringified json like this

"{\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"should\" : [\n      {\n        \"match\" : {\n          \"content\" : {\n            \"query\" : \"passport\",\n            \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n            \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n            \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n            \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n            \"lenient\" : false,\n            \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n            \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n            \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}"

mapping is same

Comment: and what is the mapping? You need to recreate the index with the mapping to `percolator` - existing mappings in Elasticsearch cannot be changed.